# how to change date format of print preview header on chrome, YYYY-MM-DD to DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: google-chrome

how to change date format of print preview on google chrome.

The current format is YYYY-MM-dd

I need to display on format dd/MM/YYYY

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you still have this problem. However, for you or anyone else facing this problem, please do the following:

- Go to Chrome language settings either through the menu or by visiting
  chrome://settings/languages on your Chrome browser.
- Click on
  language->Add languages.
- Choose English (United Kingdom) and click Add.
- Now, click on the menu button besides the newly added
  language "English (United Kingdom)".
- Check "Display Google Chrome in this language".
- Click Relaunch.

That's it.

Comment: It is really really stupid that chrome confuses language with locale.  I speak en-us but live in Germany and have a company in the UK.  This means that from a language perspective I generally prefer en-us...but from a locale (date format, number format, currency, etc) what I need varies depending on what I am doing as I have a mix of locales in my life and I can't stick to only one unless I never want to interact with another person or entity.

Answer (score 2):

It cannot be done, as far as i know.

Closest you can get is to change the "***Language and Input Settings***" in the "***Advanced Settings***" to something that has the format you want.

See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=234897